# Delete double quotes using sed but only if they are in pair

Tags: awk, sed

I have data in below format

```
"abcde" : "Blank / Not testing",
"mnop" : "12 GB 2.5\" PPT ABC",
"wxy" : "14 TB 5\" Ant Testing PART SSD"
```

I want to delete the double quotes and get the data in below format

```
abcde : Blank / Not testing
mnop : 12 GB 2.5\" PPT ABC
wxy : 14 TB 5\" Ant Testing PART SSD
```

I know I can delete all " using simple sed but ere I want to delete the sed only at start of line , before and after : and at end . Not any "which is appearing in mid of line.

Any help

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`Awk`** solution:

```
awk '{ gsub(/^"|",?$/,""); sub(/" : "/," : ") }1' file
```

The output:

```
abcde : Blank / Not testing
mnop : 12 GB 2.5\" PPT ABC
wxy : 14 TB 5\" Ant Testing PART SSD
```

Comment: Thank you .. worked perfectly .. You are always a savior :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to delete all `"` except escaped ones with GNU sed:

```
sed -E 's/(^|[^\])"/\1/g' file
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this sed too

```
sed -E 's/"([^"]*)"([^"]*)"(.*)",*/\1\2\3/' infile
```